# sbt-assembly: Rename Class with merge conflicts (shade)

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

How can I tell sbt-assembly to keep its existing merge / deduplicate rules, except, when two `.class` files conflice, rename (and issue a warning so I know about it)?

Would this be identical to the shade strategy used in Maven?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `rename` strategy literally just renames the file and it doesn't change the contents, so it won't work for .class files. The main use case for rename is for LICENSE files.

**Updated in September 2015**:

sbt-assembly 0.14.0 adds [shading](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#shading) support.

> sbt-assembly can shade classes from your projects or from the library dependencies. Backed by Jar Jar Links, bytecode transformation (via ASM) is used to change references to the renamed classes.

```scala
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("org.apache.commons.io.**" -> "shadeio.@1").inAll
)
```

Comment: Thanks.  Does sbt-assembly support anything like shade?

Comment: So there's no solution to the shading problem in sbt? Should I really change to maven? This su*ks...

Comment: There's a Github issue now to petition for this feature - https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/issues/156

Comment: And now shade support [has been merged into sbt#master](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/pull/162)!