# Should sbt-assembly perform a "maven-shade-plugin"-like relocation of classes?

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

The description of [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/blob/master/README.md) merge strategy called *rename* sounded like it might permit something similar to the shading operation of the [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html) which will relocate classes and their references to permit the management of incompatible versions of libraries.

Would it be appropriate for sbt-assembly to perform that function?

I used the following merge strategy to attempt to use rename as a relocation mechanism but while it matches all the files, it passes them straight through (which is consistent with looking at the code).

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := { s =>
  s match {
    case PathList("com", "clearspring", "analytics", _*) => {
      println("match_cs: " + s)
      MergeStrategy.rename
    }
    case x => {
       println("x: " + x)
       val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
       oldStrategy(x)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I see part of this is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24596914/sbt-assembly-rename-class-with-merge-conflicts-shade) that sbt-assembly doesn't shade.  Which leaves the part "would it be appropriate" ?

Comment: Did this ever worked??

I am in the same situation...

Comment: @acidghost : No, per my link, sbt-assembly won't do that transformation.  You just have to monkey around with sbt excludes and they are very dependent on the current set of dependent jars.

Comment: sbt now has shade support [in sbt#master via this PR](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/pull/162)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Updated in September 2015**:

sbt-assembly 0.14.0 adds [shading](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#shading) support.

> sbt-assembly can shade classes from your projects or from the library dependencies. Backed by Jar Jar Links, bytecode transformation (via ASM) is used to change references to the renamed classes.

```scala
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("org.apache.commons.io.**" -> "shadeio.@1").inAll
)
```