# How to realize maven-like dependency shading using sbt-proguard?

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

Maven's shade plugin can reorganize the struct of a jar and rewrite the affected bytecode of class files. What plugin in SBT can realize this purpose? I only found a plugin called sbt-proguard and not sure how to do it.

Comment: sbt-assembly now supports shading. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/28846389/3827

Answer (score 0):

Try the [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin. From the github page:

> sbt-assembly can shade classes from your projects or from the library
>   dependencies. Backed by Jar Jar Links, bytecode transformation (via
>   ASM) is used to change references to the renamed classes.

The documentation further describes how to define shading rules.