# Conflict between httpclient version and Apache Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm developing a Java application using Apache Spark. I use this version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

In my code, there is a transitional dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I package my application into a single JAR file. When deploying it on EC2 instance using `spark-submit`, I get this error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.getPreferredSocketFactory(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:87)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:65)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:58)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:50)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:38)
```

This error shows clearly that `SparkSubmit` has loaded an older version of the same Apache httpclient library and this conflict happens for this reason.

What is a good way to solve this issue?

For some reason, I cannot upgrade Spark on my Java code. However, I could do that with the EC2 cluster easily. Is it possible to deploy my java code on a cluster with a higher version say 1.6.1 version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As said in your post, Spark is loading an older version of the `httpclient`. The solution is to use the Maven's [`relocation`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html) facility to produce a neat conflict-free project.

Here's an example of how to use it in your `pom.xml` file :

```
<project>
  <!-- Your project definition here, with the groupId, artifactId, and it's dependencies --> 
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <relocations>
                <relocation>
                  <pattern>org.apache.http.client</pattern>
                  <shadedPattern>shaded.org.apache.http.client</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
              </relocations>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

This will move all files from `org.apache.http.client` to `shaded.org.apache.http.client`, resolving the conflict.

---

**Original post :**

If this is simply a matter of transitive dependencies, you could just add this to your `spark-core` dependency to exclude the HttpClient used by Spark :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I also added the `scope` as `provided` in your dependency as it will be provided by your cluster.

However, that might muck around with Spark's internal behaviour. If you still get an error after doing this, you could try using Maven's [`relocation`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html) facility that should produce a neat conflict-free project.

Regarding the fact you can't upgrade Spark's version, did you use exactly [this dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10/1.6.1) declaration from mvnrepository ?

Spark being backwards compatible, there shouldn't be any problem deploying your job on a cluster with a higher version.

Comment: The problem was indeed solved by relocation. If you elaborate on how to use `apache-shade-plugin`, I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: @M-T-A Glad it helped. I updated my answer, however can you confirm I am refering to the right package in the pattern tags ?

Comment: Note, you may need to set the pattern as the following to fix the issue for http.conn as well.:
<pattern>org.apache.http.</pattern>
<shadedPattern>shaded.org.apache.http.</shadedPattern>

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was really helpful! I am adding a Link to another issue that explains how to [relocate via SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846389/should-sbt-assembly-perform-a-maven-shade-plugin-like-relocation-of-classes) as this might be helpful, like it was for me.