# Scalatra application with spark dependency returns java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE due to multiple httpclient versions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, scalatra

I'm trying to build an Scalatra application that runs code with spark. I can actually build the fat jar with `sbt-assembly` and the endpoints work, but when running tests with `org.scalatra.test.scalatest._` I get the following error:

```
*** RUN ABORTED ***
  java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:146)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:964)
  at org.scalatra.test.HttpComponentsClient$class.createClient(HttpComponentsClient.scala:100)
  at my.package.MyServletTests.createClient(MyServletTests.scala:5)
  at org.scalatra.test.HttpComponentsClient$class.submit(HttpComponentsClient.scala:63)
  at my.package.MyServletTests.submit(MyServletTests.scala:5)
  at org.scalatra.test.Client$class.post(Client.scala:62)
  at my.package.MyServletTests.post(MyServletTests.scala:5)
  at org.scalatra.test.Client$class.post(Client.scala:60)
  at my.package.MyServletTests.post(MyServletTests.scala:5)
  ...
```

From other sources, this seemed to be an `httpclient` version error, since both Scalatra and Spark use different versions. These sources suggested the use of Maven Shade Plugin to rename one of these versions. I am, however, using sbt instead of Maven. Even though sbt has a shade functionality, it works when creating the fat jar, and I need this solution during development tests.
Sources are:

- [Conflict between httpclient version and Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843400/conflict-between-httpclient-version-and-apache-spark)
- [Error while trying to use an API. java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32793830/error-while-trying-to-use-an-api-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-instance)

Is there any way to resolve this kind of conflict using SBT? I'm running Eclipse Scala-IDE and these are my dependencies in `built.sbt`:

```
val scalatraVersion = "2.6.5"

// scalatra
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatra"  %% "scalatra"           % scalatraVersion,
  "org.scalatra"  %% "scalatra-scalatest" % scalatraVersion % "test",
  "org.scalatra"  %% "scalatra-specs2"    % scalatraVersion,
  "org.scalatra"  %% "scalatra-swagger"   % scalatraVersion,
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic"    % "1.2.3" % "runtime",
  "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp"    % "9.4.9.v20180320" % "container;compile",
  "javax.servlet"  % "javax.servlet-api"  % "3.1.0" % "provided"
)

// From other projects:
// spark
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.0",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.4.0",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.0"
)

// scalatest
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "3.0.5" % "test"
```

Comment: did you find solution for this